# c++ ifstream end of line

Tags: c++, char, fstream, end-of-line

I have a file that looks like this:

```
e r g d g d
f h d r h f
..........
```

And I want to store these characters in a two-dimensional array

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream file("file.txt");
    char c[20][20];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        while(!end of line?)
        {
            file >> c[i][j];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
.....
}
```

how do i do this? 
or how to find number of characters in a line?

Comment: `char` is not a two dimensional array

Comment: does each line have the same number of characters?

Comment: @tobi303 i fixed it

Comment: yes each line has the same number of characters

Comment: why do you use a `char[20][20]` when each line contains only 6 characters?

Comment: if your question is how to know if you reached the end of the line, then the answer is a) you dont have to care, just continue reading, or b) when you read 6 numbers you reached the end of the line :P

Comment: @tobi303 that's the max number, it isn't important

Comment: what if there is more than 6 characters in the line, i gave an example

Comment: you just said that the number of characters per line is always the same....

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ the question is about end of line, not about end of file. So even if OPs code has wrong usage of `eof` it is not a duplicate

Comment: why not getline(file, variable), that goes one line at a time, and have that variable be a string, then parse it out and store into the array  you want.

Comment: Each line has the same number of characters, which is not always 6, the file i included was an example

Comment: @Omid CompSCI how do I parse it out...

Comment: you dont need any parsing, just read whatever number of characters you have per line and then continue with the next line. For `cin` it doesnt matter if the characters are seperated by a space or a new line

Comment: that would be easy, the question is how to find the number of characters in a line

Comment: @jeff Like I said, when you use getline and store into a string, before you read the new line again, do stringVariable.length(), and you will know how many characters were on that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `eof()` like you do.  You have to perform an I/O read operation before you can then use `eof()`.

For what you are attempting, you should use `std::getline()` instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("file.txt");
    std::string line;
    char c[20][20] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        if (!std::getline(file, line))
            break;

        std::istringstream iss(line);
        for(j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
        {
            if (!(iss >> c[i][j]))
                break;
        }
    }

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, you should consider using `std::vector` instead of fixed-sized arrays (unless you know for a fact that your file will *never* exceed 20 lines and/or 20 characters per line):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("file.txt");
    std::vector<std::vector<char> > c;
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        std::vector<char> tmp;

        std::copy(
            std::istream_iterator<char>(iss),
            std::istream_iterator<char>(),
            std::back_inserter(tmp)
        );

        /* which is equivalent to:
        char ch;
        while (iss >> ch) {
            tmp.push_back(ch);
        }
        */

        c.push_back(tmp);
    }

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<char> CharVector;

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, CharVector &out)
{
    out.clear();

    std::string line;
    if (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        std::copy(
            std::istream_iterator<char>(iss),
            std::istream_iterator<char>(),
            std::back_inserter(out)
        );

        /* which is equivalent to:
        char ch;
        while (iss >> ch) {
            out.push_back(ch);
        }
        */
    }

    return in;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("file.txt");
    std::vector<CharVector> c;

    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<CharVector>(file),
        std::istream_iterator<CharVector>(),
        std::back_inserter(c)
    );

    /* which is equivalent to:
    CharVector cv;
    while (file >> cv) {
        c.push_back(cv);
    }
    */

    ...

    return 0;
}
```